# Is there a solution to accomodate multiple users making updates to the same database`

Tags: database, concurrency

We are looking at building a solution where multiple users are viewing rows in a database in different ways and some of those users are updating columns in those rows so that another group of users see their updates.

The solution we used to use is Excel on a MS Sharepoint website. Each row in the Excel document represented rows in the database, and whenever a user wanted to update a column in a row, they would change a cell in the Excel document and that would be almost immediately broadcast to any other user also viewing that Sharepoint Excel document.

The problem arose when too many people were viewing the document and the security level on an Excel document is practically non-existed.
What other solutions are out there besides:

a)  SqlServer database with website front end

b)  SqlServer database with fat pc client front end

c)  Cloud db (like Snowflake) with some other front end?

Comment: All those solutions will work. Any database will store data concurrently. The cost is on building the front end application that displays the data in a suitable way, with security and automatic updates. Also, you need to handle simultaneous updates gracefully.

Comment: @TheImpaler, are there examples already out there which handle security and auto-updates?

Comment: Regarding the backend databases, all of them have some form of auto-updates. When it comes to the front end, the solution provider will need to provide them.